# Testing python code for correct values

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have written some python code and it already updates the databases with correct results. I want to use some mock data and be able to test every line and edge for this code. I have learned some concepts in class for testing java, but I have no idea how to do it for python and didn't really grasp the concept of writing good tests. I have added my code for the stuff I want to test. If anyone please explain how for me to test this code that would be great. I have added a little of the test code myself, but I don't know if it is right or wrong. I have researched online to help me, but most of the documentation was on very simple functions and not something similar to my code so not very sure how it should be done.

My Code:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), os.pardir))
import mySqlConnector

database = mySqlConnector.mySqlConnector(1, 2014)

result = database.getUserPicksWithSeed()

updatedUsers = dict()

for row in result: 
  id = row["userID"]
  if id not in updatedUsers:
    updatedUsers[id] = 0

  seed1 = row["seed1"]
  seed2 = row["seed2"]

  if seed1 > seed2:
      pointField = seed1 - seed2
  else:
      pointField = seed2 - seed1

  if pointField < 5: 
      pointField = pointField * 0.75

  upsetHappened = row["upsetHappened"]

  if not (upsetHappened == 1):
      pointField = pointField / (-3)

  updatedUsers[id] += pointField

for key, value in updatedUsers.items(): 
      database.updateUserScoreById(key, value)
```

Test Code (so far):

```
import os.path, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), os.pardir))
import mySqlConnector
import pytest

database = mySqlConnector.mySqlConnector(1, 2014)



users = {
  'USERID' : 1,
  'USERID2' : 2,
  'USERID3' : 3
  }

seeds = {
  'seed1_1' : 1,
  'seed1_2' : 8,
  'seed1_3' : 7,
  'seed2_1' : 16,
  'seed2_2' : 9,
  'seed3_2' : 4
}
```